# Habilitar fullscreen en android con java

Tags: java, android

Necesito poner **fullscreen** la pantalla del app, he puesto en el *mainActivity* de acuerdo a un tutorial que estoy siguiendo:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Actividad full screen
        this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
        );
    }
}
```

Pero me dice:

> 'setSystemUiVisibility(int)' is deprecated

En *Kotlin* para activar el modo inmersivo o fullscreen hacen lo siguiente:

```
window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)
```

Estoy investigando como hacerlo con java usando **androidx** pero no encuentro una opción.

Comment: Hola, ¿Estas usando Kotlin o Java?

Comment: java solamente eso supongo que hace el tutorial. Olvide agregar que tambien puse antes del oncreate @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) no se exactamente que quiere decir eso.

Comment: @Israel-ICM voy a tenerlo en cuenta ya que este tambien oculta el teclado

Comment: Huy perdona @FreddyDaniel no se en que estaba pensando XD, quise referirme a que pruebes con `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar"` en el manifest.xml en el activity que necesitas

Comment: Ah no ser que necesites hacerlo si o si desde JAVA

Comment: @Israel-ICM El código obselote funciona, quita el action bar pero esta deprecado, cuando puse eso en el manifest tambien funciona :D gracias

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que ponerlo a la vista principal, la cual siempre al crear un proyecto es un constraintLayout.

De esto se hablo en el 2017 en la droidCoin [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_mGDMVRO3iE&t=733s) 9:30 esta todo lo que buscas, hasta como obtener los tamaños de las decoraciones del windows.

```
myView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)
```

Comment: Hola es lo mismo que e utilizado, esto seria:  this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);

Comment: Comento en la pregunta que setSystemUiVisibility es obsoleto.

Comment: @FreddyDaniel tu lo haces al window lo que esta mal. Tienes que hacer a la vista principal de tu activity.

Comment: No sabría como hacerlo.